# Can other improvements be built on the same tile as a road?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization V, can other improvements be built on the same tile as a road?

Comment: Also be aware that if you *do* attempt to do something which replaces the current improvement, the game warns you and asks if you're sure you want to replace it.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, they can. In fact, you can build a road alongside ANY other upgrade (except of course for the railroad, which replaces it).

Comment: I will confirm this. No ambivalence required. A resounding yes.

Comment: Given that the answer was correct, might want to flag it as accurate.